# I can not install "AVS Video Editor"

Tags: windows, windows-xp

After reinstalling Windows XP pro sp-3, I started the installation of "AVS Video Editor 6.5.1" and the message comes: 
**C: \ Program Files \ AVS4Y0U \ AV5VideoEditor \ Data \ SampleProject \ Content \ Diving07.avi 
An error occurred while trying to copy a file: The source file Is corrupted. 
Click Retry to try again, Ignore to skip this file (not recommended), or Abort to cancel installation.** 
Does anyone know, what's the problem